# A Bug While Trying Google APIs?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I was reading text to speech API document at following URL

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/voices/list

There is a "Try it" link in the menu. I clicked it to just see how it works.

It didn't let me try it until I make a google cloud account, which required my credit card number. which is not a big deal.

Then I was asked to create a project, which I also did.
Then I was asked to link my cloud account to some developer account which I don't even remember what was it.
Then I was given a badge which I'm still not sure what was it, because it disappeared so fast that I only could read the title.

Then I get error that Google want to open a popup but blocked by browser which I allowed it.
Then I get an error (picture at bottom).

Then I tried to contact support and get help with this error which I was forwarded to stack-overflow a place that I wouldn't even think I post something to get support!

[image: ask for help in Stackoverflow]

And the error that I'm not sure how google engineer would want to help me with in SO

**Note**: I am not the one closing the popup. First time it opened, asked me to link my cloud account to some developer account. then after doing all that, It open, and closes after few seconds, without any interaction from me.

`"Error authorizing: popup_closed_by_user"`

[image: "Error authorizing: popup_closed_by_user"]

Comment: When you use the `Try this API` , it saves you the trouble of setting up your own client in Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) , This error mean you literally closed the pop up that give you the consent screen, you can always try incognito with fresh cookies to retry.

Comment: That popup literally closes itself without any interference from me (Which I also mentioned in my question). between opening and closing the popup there isn't even 1 second delay which means I can't even check console for errors, or even copy the link to try and open it in tab instead. BTW I believe browser tabs are in use for very long and popup blockers are also implemented in browser for very long time which makes this kind of implementation really bad.

Comment: Have you tried in incognito mode or other browser, it sounds like an addon on your browser that does that. On the other hand, you can test the API in the "OAuth playground" https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ or just develop the login yourself.

Comment: Actually I don't need it anymore, I have implemented my own client and done with the project. just wanted to reach out to developer and let them know that there is a bug in their design. Also Incognito will not make a difference, once the authenticate completed, popup , next times will not even stay open, and close immediately.

Comment: I am frequently working with these these explorers and never had issue like that, even the one mentioned here I tried it and it worked fine so it has to be something local to you that caused the issue, either way I am glad you have it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try again in a browser with all browser plugins deactivated and cache and cookies deleted. This worked for me after having the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, browser plugin, cookie or cache is not the issue. I'm sorry, but your answer is not good one even for end user support of a website. Google still uses popup window while it has been obsolete since 2010. to identify user, and for security purposes, it relies on HTTP headers that can be manipulated easily by end user, such as HTTP referer and browser agent.